# Getting connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out) in ftp connect

Tags: android, ftp, ftp-client

I have been using ftp to upload images on server in android application and I'm using the following code to connect with ftp. it's working fine in Wi-fi but if I switched to 3G or 2G connection, I am getting connection time out error. So would you please let me know how to take care of this situation. And my client is also facing this issue in Veriozon, Sprint, ATT network provider too. It's iPhone version is working fine in all network.

**Code :**

```
try {
                    ftpClient = new FTPClient();
                    ftpClient.setConnectTimeout(30);
                    ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName(server));

                    boolean isLogin = ftpClient.login(username, password);
                    boolean workingDir = ftpClient
                            .changeWorkingDirectory(path);

                    if (ftpClient.getReplyString().contains("250")) {

                        ftpClient
                                .setFileType(org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

                        buffIn = new BufferedInputStream(
                                new FileInputStream(filePath));
                        ftpClient.enterLocalActiveMode();
                        // ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

                        ProgressInputStream progressInput = new ProgressInputStream(
                                buffIn, progressHandler);

                        isUploaded = ftpClient.storeFile(fileName,
                                progressInput);

                        buffIn.close();
                        ftpClient.logout();
                        ftpClient.disconnect();
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,
                                            R.string.postimage_uploaderror,
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    });
                }
```

**Error :**

> java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to Host (port 21):
>   connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

I have imported "commons-net-ftp-2.0.jar" and commons-net-3.3.jar in my project.

Looking forward for your answer.

Best Regards,

Devang

Comment: did you check your server is it on ?

Comment: yes, its on. Its working fine in wi-fi network.

Comment: checked with wifi now and its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Normally a 3G or 2G connection is slower than wifi this is why you get a Connection Timeout error. to encounter this you need to set the timeout delay for your FTP client and you can do it by adding this line

```
ftpClient.setConnectTimeout(30); // 30 mSeconds increase it for more time
```

so your code will become :

```
ftpClient.setConnectTimeout(30);
ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName(server));
boolean isLogin = ftpClient.login(username, password);
boolean workingDir = ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(path);
```

EDIT

increase the timeout to 50s (50000)

```
ftpClient.setConnectTimeout(50000); // 50 Seconds increase it for more time
```

Comment: Okay, but my client using Veriozon, Sprint, ATT 4G network and he is having same issue. So do you have any idea about it.

Comment: it's the same problem which is the timeout, you need to give your FTP client the amount of time to wait before closing the connection

Comment: I have used connection time out but still having same issue.

Comment: getting exception at this line ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName(server));. And my server is pointing to amazon.

Comment: I think you should check your connection to the Amazon server

Comment: @Devang increase the timeout to 50000 (5s)

Comment: now I am getting this exception "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /54.200.0.36 (port 21) after 50000ms"

Comment: add this socket timeout method ftpclient.setSoTimeOut(50000)