# Couldn't Fetch JSON data because of connection timeout

Tags: android, connection-timeout, android-json

I have a spring-boot web service that produces JSON data, which runs in my local machine `http://localhost:8080/demo/services`.

I tried to get the JSON data using my IP address but it gave following error in LogCat:

```
09-23 15:18:27.897 2923-3540/com.example.palangou.foodie1 
    W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.9
    (port 8080): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
```

The relevant Java code is:

```
new JSONpart().execute("http://192.168.1.9:8080/demo/services");

public class JSONpart extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<POJO>> {


    @Override
    protected List<POJO> doInBackground(String... urls) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String place = "", name = "";
        List<POJO> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            try {
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

                String line = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                Log.d("Recursive places",buffer.toString());
                String finalJSON = buffer.toString();
                try {
                    //JSONObject object = new JSONObject(finalJSON);
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(finalJSON);

                    for(int i=0;i< array.length();i++)
                    {//Log.d("Recursive places",     finalobject.getString("name"));
                        POJO pojo = new POJO();
                        JSONObject finalobject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        pojo.setName(finalobject.getString("service"));
                        pojo.setPlace(finalobject.getString("servicedesc"));
                       //
                        arraylist.add(pojo);

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
              //  Log.d("name", arraylist.get(1).getName().toString());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            ;
        } finally {
            connection.disconnect();
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
       // return buffer.toString();
         return  arraylist;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<POJO> s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
       // Log.d("OnPOST", s.get(1).getName().toString());
        FoodiesAdapater adapter = new FoodiesAdapater(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row,s);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);



    }
}
```

Comment: is your api is working ??

Comment: Did you connect to the same wifi that your pc is connected to?

Comment: check you server is on or not!

Comment: are u using Genymotion or any real device ?

Comment: In addition to the point raised by user6556461, also follow the answer in here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886578/getting-connect-failed-etimedout-connection-timed-out-in-ftp-connect

Comment: @Trish: Yes the API works

Comment: @quicklearner I use a real device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check whether your api or the url is working. It would be better if you upload your Json file to this http://myjson.com/ and get a url from this online server.

Comment: Also you can check whether your Json is working or not in this link <json2csharp.com>

Comment: Strange that this worked because the LogCat didn't show the problem was with that. @GouthamPalani can you explain a bit here? :)

Comment: @Sufian I just used myjson.com to fetch data. I manually uploaded my JSON file there

Comment: The problem was never with the JSON. It was with accessing the API. Your device wasn't on the same network as pointed out in comments under your question.